# The classifying space of an infinite totally ordered set is contractible

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261999/classifying-space-infinite-totally-ordered-set-contractible) on math.stackexchange, but no one answered.

Let $(X,\le)$ be a totally ordered set. Regarding it as a category, it has a classifying space $B(X,\le)=|N_\bullet(X,\le)|$. This should be the (possible infinite) simplex with vertices $X$, hence I expect it to be contractible.

However, I was not able to explicitly prove contractibility starting from the definition $$B(X,\le)=(\coprod_{i\in\mathbb{N}_0}N_i(X,\le)\times\Delta^i)/\tilde{} $$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: A finite totally ordered set has a maximum so it has a final object as a category and its classifying space is contractible. On the other hand $X$ can be considered as a direct limit of its finite (ordered) subsets and so its classifying space is a direct limit of contractible spaces hence contractible.

Comment: Any filtered category has contractible classifying space. First source is, I guess, Quillen's "Higher algebraic K-theory" (in the Springer LNM 341), with very nice proof.

Comment: Here is a proof sketch. First, a lemma: if a $T_1$-space $Z$ is a filtered colimit of subspaces $Z_i$ which are closed under intersection, and each $Z_i$ contains only finitely many other $Z_j$'s, then every compact subspace of $Z$ is contained in some $Z_i$. Corollary: Under these conditions, if the $Z_i$'s are contractible, then $Z$ must be weakly contractible, since every sphere in $Z$ factors through some $Z_i$. In conclusion, the space $BX$ is weakly contractible since it is a filtered colimit of contractible simplices. Hence, the CW-complex $BX$ is contractible.

Comment: @Mostafa Do you have a reference for the claim that a directed colimit of contractible spaces is contractible? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @ToddTrimble For a direct limit of connected pointed spaces, I think  the limit commutes with homotopy groups and in the case of contractible CW-complexes it implies that the limit is also contractible, true?

Comment: @Mostafa It's possible to adduce some such argument, perhaps, but it would help if you were more careful with language. "Direct limit" to me is a synonym for "colimit" and it's not true that homotopy group functors preserve all colimits (see e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320812/fundamental-group-of-the-wedge-sum-of-two-spaces). Aside from that, the statement in your first comment that I was asking about was stated more generally than for spaces having the homotopy type of a CW complex, which is why I asked. (If you don't think it's true in that extra generality, that's fine.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble What I mean by "direct limit" is a colimit over a inductive ordered set. It seems it's not standard, what is the standard word for this concept?

Comment: @Mostafa In an earlier comment I used the phrase "directed colimit", which I believe is pretty standard. (I thought you might have meant this. The nLab http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/directed+colimit notes that "direct limit" is also sometimes used, so I guess my earlier comment was overly harsh, although I do find that "direct limit" is confusing because of the synonymous usage noted above).

Comment: @ToddTrimble Filtered colimits (of simplicial sets) preserve weak homotopy equivalences, hence filtered colimits of weakly contractible simplicial sets are weakly contractible. Since the space in question is the geometric realisation of a simplicial set, this proves the claim.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, thanks; got it. And I expect that might have been all Mostafa meant in his first comment, although he made a statement that was more general, that directed colimits of contractible spaces are contractible. Any feeling about that?

Comment: It's probably not true without hypotheses on the diagram. It suffices that the functor $\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{sSet}$ preserve the colimit in question. I guess that happens if the arrows in the diagram are closed $T_1$-embeddings.

Answer (score 7):

Let $P$ be any partially ordered set.  For any map $x\colon P\to [0,1]$, put $\sigma(x)=\{p\in P:x(p)>0\}$. Then $BP$ can be identified with the set of maps $x$ such that $\sigma(x)$ is finite and totally ordered, and $\sum_px(p)=1$.  Now suppose that $a$ is an element of $P$ which is comparable with every other element, and define $e\colon P\to [0,1]$ by $e(a)=1$ and $e(p)=0$ for $p\neq a$.  It is then easy to see that the map $h_t(x)=(1-t)x+te$ preserves $BP$ and gives a contraction.  This construction is most often used when $a$ is largest or smallest in $P$, but you really only need it to be comparable with every element of $P$.  In particular, if $P$ is nonempty and totally ordered then you can choose $a$ arbitrarily.

As another way to look at this, if $f,g\colon P\to Q$ are two poset maps, and $f(p)\leq g(p)$ for all $p$, then it is standard that $Bf$ is homotopic to $Bg$.  If $P$ is totally ordered, we can define $f,g,h\colon P\to P$ by $f(p)=p$ and $g(p)=\max(a,p)$ and $h(p)=a$.  Then $f\leq g\geq h$, so $Bf$, $Bg$ and $Bh$ are homotopic, but $Bf$ is the identity and $Bh$ is constant.

Comment: Which topology should one use on the set of maps $x$, which are identified with $BP$? The one coming from the (possible infinite) product $[0,1]^P$?

Comment: The space $BP$ is topologised as the colimit of the spaces $BQ$, as $Q$ runs over finite subsets of $P$.  So a subset $F\subset BP$ is closed iff $F\cap BQ$ is closed with respect to the obvious topology on $BQ$, for all $Q$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a reference for the standard fact about homotopic maps on classifying spaces induced by order-preserving maps between posets?

Comment: The two maps combine to give a poset map $\{0,1\}\times P\to Q$, and $B(\{0,1\}\times P)=[0,1]\times BP$.

Comment: So if (nonempty) $P$ merely has binary joins, the same argument as in the second paragraph shows $BP$ is contractible. This hadn't occurred to me before now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you consider this explicit, but here you go:

Choose a point $x_0\in X$, and let $F\colon X\to X$ be the functor that sends $x$ to itself if $x\geq x_0$, and to $x_0$ otherwise. There is a zig-zag of natural transformations
$$x_0\leq F(x)\geq x$$
between the constant functor $x_0$ and the identity functor, because $X$ is totally ordered. On classifying spaces this gives a homotopy between the constant map $x_0$ and the identity.

Comment: Emanuele, isn't this just the argument given in Neil's second paragraph?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the same... I should have read more carefully.